# OpenXML SpreadsheetDocument SaveAs() giving file-in-use error

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-powertools

I'm trying to generate an Excel spreadsheet dynamically, using OpenXMLPowerTools v4.5.3.2, DocumentFormat.OpenXML v2.9.1, called from a ASP.Net Core web app.

I've verified that able to generate the spreadsheet OK.

The problem is that I need to generate the spreadsheet ... and return it as a MEMORY STREAM (so the ASP.Net Core web controller

**HCExcelReport.cs:**

```
   class HCExcelReport
    {
        protected SpreadsheetDocument doc;
        protected MemorySpreadsheet ms;
        protected string tmpFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();

        public MemoryStream Generate(List<CandidateRecords> candidateRecords)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
            using (OpenXmlMemoryStreamDocument streamDoc = OpenXmlMemoryStreamDocument.CreateSpreadsheetDocument())
            {
                doc = streamDoc.GetSpreadsheetDocument();
                ms = new MemorySpreadsheet();

                ...
                // Save to disk=
                doc.SaveAs(tmpFile);  // <-- Successfully writes .. but file remains open
                doc.Dispose();   // <-- file *STILL* remains open
            }

            // Copy to memory stream
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(tmpFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))  // <-- Exception: the file is in use by another process!!!!
            {
                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
            }
            return memoryStream;
```

I've tried countless things ...

... But if I use PowerTools, I don't see any alternatives to `doc.SaveAs()`...

... And if I use `doc.SaveAs()`, the file seems to remain "in use" until my web app exits.

Q: Any suggestions?

Comment: Please look at this post
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167136/how-to-copy-a-file-while-it-is-being-used-by-another-process">How to copy a file while it is being used by another process</a>
regards marcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this post [How to copy a file while it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167136/how-to-copy-a-file-while-it-is-being-used-by-another-process)

```
// Copy to memory stream
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    memoryStream  = new MemoryStream();
    fs.CopyTo(memoryStream );
    fs.Close();
}
return memoryStream;
```

regards marcel

Comment: Thank you, but I wound up giving up on OpenXMLPowerTools.  It shouldn't have unnecessarily left the file "locked", and I shouldn't have to go to "extreme measures" (like using Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS), as cited in your link).  Your solution (fs.CopyTo()) is a lot less drastic ... but it still shouldn't be necessary.  Thank you anyway.  And let me "accept" your reply :)